# CSS: Ordered List from positive to negative without zero?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

**Is it possible to create an ordered list with positive to negative without zero using only CSS?**
Example:

```
 3. Highest
 2. Higher
 1. High
-1. Low
-2. Lower
-3. Lowest
```

I understand the presentation is highly unusual. The intent is to create, with one field, a list of most and least favorites.

Some technical background: The field is generated in [Joomla! CMS](https://www.joomla.org/) via [FLEXIcontent's Text Field](https://flexicontent.org/features/fields.html). The field is configured to be able to take multiple entries, and is restricted to only be able to take an even number of entries. The user is required to input an equal number of pros and cons for the given field. I'd like to be able to control everything exclusively in CSS so I don't have to create template overrides, if at all possible.

I've chosen this approach as I don't want to require multiple fields for one set.

I've found various resources for styling the numbers. I believe the following wouldn't work as I'd have to control some factors with PHP or there's limits to the markup:

```
<ol>
    <li value=#>List Item</li> <!--needs value populated by PHP-->
</ol>

<ol reversed> <!--Stays positive and ends at 1-->
    <li>Reversed List</li> 
</ol>

<ol reversed start=2> <!--Can I control where to start based on number of children?-->
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li>List Item 3</li>
  <li>List Item 4</li>
  <li>List Item 5</li>
</ol>
```

If the task is completely impossible, it may be more practical to style based on number of children and color the first and last half differently. Still, it'd be very interesting to see if this is possible with CSS exclusively.

Comment: So what you want to do is color the positive and negative halves of the list differently?

Comment: That's probably the most reasonable approach. But the initial intent is to create a unique ordered list as shown in the first code block.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://css-tricks.com/numbering-in-style/)

Answer (score 4):

Great question! This is something a little different and an interesting example of what CSS can do.

See the code below for a solution to your problem. If you are using SASS you could easily create a mixin to generate all the selectors you need.

By using CSS counters you can fake the list number and then use `nth-child` to reset the counter to avoid displaying a `0` item.

**Solution with a starting number**

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 1.5em;
}

ol[start="1"] {
  counter-reset: ol 2;
}

ol[start="1"] li:nth-child(2) {
  counter-reset: ol 0;
}

ol[start="2"] {
  counter-reset: ol 3;
}

ol[start="2"] li:nth-child(3) {
  counter-reset: ol 0;
}

ol[start="3"] {
  counter-reset: ol 4;
}

ol[start="3"] li:nth-child(4) {
  counter-reset: ol 0;
}

ol li::before {
  counter-increment: ol -1;
  content: counter(ol) '.';
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 -1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h2>Start at 1</h2>
<ol start="1">
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
  <li>List item 4</li>
  <li>List item 5</li>
  <li>List item 6</li>
</ol>

<h2>Start at 2</h2>
<ol start="2">
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
  <li>List item 4</li>
  <li>List item 5</li>
  <li>List item 6</li>
</ol>

<h2>Start at 3</h2>
<ol start="3">
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
  <li>List item 4</li>
  <li>List item 5</li>
  <li>List item 6</li>
</ol>
```

**Solution without starting number but with same number of positive and negative list items**

If you want this to work without having to add the `start` attribute to the `ol` and always have the same number of positive and negative list items you can use this CSS - but again it requires that you write it out the selectors for all the required numbers of items.

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 1.5em;
}

/* two items */

ol li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2) {
  counter-reset: ol 2;
}

ol li:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(1) {
  counter-reset: ol 0;
}

/* fouritems */

ol li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(4) {
  counter-reset: ol 3;
}

ol li:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(2) {
  counter-reset: ol 0;
}

/* six items */

ol li:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(6) {
  counter-reset: ol 4;
}

ol li:nth-child(4):nth-last-child(3) {
  counter-reset: ol 0;
}


ol li::before {
  counter-increment: ol -1;
  content: counter(ol) '.';
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 -1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h2>Two Items</h2>
<ol>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
</ol>

<h2>Four Items</h2>
<ol>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
  <li>List item 4</li>
</ol>

<h2>Six Items</h2>
<ol>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
  <li>List item 4</li>
  <li>List item 5</li>
  <li>List item 6</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Very cool! Am I right in thinking, though, that start="#", for an undetermined amount of entries, would require PHP? If that's the case, I suppose I could hard-set the number of entries required.

Comment: If the start number has no limit then using PHP would make more sense as you don't want to have to write potentially 1000s of selectors. However, if you know the highest number you can create more selectors until that number - either using a SASS or LESS mixin to automatically generate all the selectors, or manually copying and pasting and changing the numbers.

Comment: I've updated my answer as I believe you are not interested in the starting # and always want the list to contain the same amount of positive and negative list numbers